# How can i keep randomizing the title in Ruby2D?

Tags: ruby2d

how can i keep randomizing the background and the title forever in Ruby2D?(Yes i want to destroy my computer)
Now,I tried this but it didnt work:

```
require 'ruby2d'
set background: 'random'//this worked,but when i try to add a loop to it,nope
set title: 'random'//this maked the title 'random'
```

i hope you can help me
UPDATE:
I managed to fix the background

Comment: Share how do you manage the background problem

Answer (score 0):

When you set background, **random** is a keyword, but when you use it for title is like a normal word.

Try this:

```
require 'ruby2d'

def generate_code(number)
  charset = Array('A'..'Z') + Array('a'..'z')
  Array.new(number) { charset.sample }.join
end


random_title = generate_code(20) 
set title: random_title
set background: 'random' #this worked,but when i try to add a loop to it,nope


show
```